# Toggle previous and next table on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building on a previous question that I had asked here. There are numerous tables on the page in a div that has a button, when you click the button it should collapse the current table and expand the next one. However I am having issues getting the code to do that.

[See working JSfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/wsfj1cqe/5/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-step').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('ul').next('table').slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle(0);
        $(this).closest('ul').next().next('.pages').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next-step').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest().prev('ul').prev('toggle-step').find('span').slideToggle(0);
        $(this).closest('.pages').slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).closest('div').prev('table').slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).closest('div').next('.table-wrapper').children('table').slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: How tied are you to the structure of your HTML? Is it coming from a database or something? Without going too much into it, if you had the ability to do this differently... I would highly suggest it. The entirety of this structure seems like a headache that will become worse as you move forward.

Comment: Unfortunately this is mostly inherited HTML so I can't change that.

Comment: Whatever inherited HTML means post it so we can inherit a better understanding of your problem, add CSS while you're at it, I've never seen an image slider that had been independent of CSS.